# Does weak convergence in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ imply weak convergence of the weak derivatives in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be bounded and consider a sequence of functions $(u_n)_n\subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $u_n\rightharpoonup u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Can we then say that $\partial_i u_n \rightharpoonup \partial_iu$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ for $i=\overline{1,N}$?

My progress: since the inclusion $H^1_0(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ is compact, eventually passing to a subsequence we can assume that $u_n\to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. This allows us to assume that $u_n(x)\to u(x)$ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$ by again eventually passing to a subsequence. I wasn't able to use any of these general facts, I only thought that maybe it is enough to write the definition of $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, i.e. $$\int_\Omega \nabla u_n\cdot \nabla v \to \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$$ for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. This implies that $$\int_\Omega \partial_i u \cdot \partial_iv\to \int_\Omega \partial_i u \cdot \partial_i v$$ for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Now if for any $w\in L^2(\Omega)$ there would be some $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $w=\partial_i v$, then we would be done. I am not sure if this is true however and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I believe your question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196073/weak-convergence-in-h1-0-and-l2?rq=1).

Comment: @cs89 that question shows that $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, which is something that I know, I am interested in $\partial_i u_n \rightharpoonup \partial_i u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe you can handle the $1D$ case with $\Omega = (0,1)$ by setting $v(x) := \int_0^x w - \bar{w}$ where $\bar{w}$ is the mean of $w$?

Comment: @cs89 I am pretty sure that you can handle the $1D$ case like that, but I wonder how to do this in $N$ dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping $u \mapsto \partial_i u$ is linear and continuous (bounded) from $H^1_0(\Omega)$  to $L^2(\Omega)$. Both are easy to verify. (If you have any trouble with these claims: please leave a comment.)

Since linear and continuous operators map weakly converging sequences to weakly converging sequences, the claim follows.

Comment: Such an elegant way to see this, I felt that this was something basic, but I couldn't come up with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one way to go is the following. Take some $w \in L^2(\Omega)$. Then $\partial_i w \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ is actually in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ (the topological dual of $H^1_0(\Omega)$), where the pairing is defined as
$$
\langle \partial_i w, u \rangle_{H^{-1},H^1_0} = - \int_\Omega w \partial_i u.
$$
By the Riesz representation theorem, since $\partial_i w \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is a linear form on $H^1_0(\Omega)$, you can represent it as a scalar product with some $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Hence
$$
\langle \partial_i w, u \rangle_{H^{-1},H^1_0} = \int_\Omega \nabla v \nabla u.
$$
Thus,
$$
- \int_\Omega w \partial_i u_n
= \int_\Omega \nabla v \nabla u_n
\to \int_\Omega \nabla v \nabla u
= - \int_\Omega w \partial_i u.
$$

Comment: to me this looks correct, nicely done.